# How to turn on submenu triangle from code for a MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, role

I generate and set my own context menus and group the items into submenus as per

```
SubTitle.Items.Add(..);
```

These popup submenus work fine, almost all is nice .. but...

I cannot get the submenu triangle to show up **UNLESS** i set the MenuItem Role (which you can set per Trigger in Style) to e.g. TopLevelHeader etc.

MenuItem.Role has no direct setter, so i would be obliged to create my submenu MenuItems as XAML static objects that i then endow with nice styles and so they'd get the submenu triangles, too.

The problem is, my context menus are fully programatically derived from e.g. a DB and if I reuse static XAML MenuItems i need set Garbage Collector onto them to break Parent relationship before i can reuse them, and/or i have to know no of these elements in advance.

Is there some way to:

```
MenuItemThatIsTitle.Role = MenuItemRole.TopLevelHeader; 
//(in order to get the triangle?)
```

..from the code?

===

example code - adding a submenu to context menu from code:

```
            contextM.Items.Add(new Separator());
            var TitleH = new MenuItem
            {
                    Header = SettingsDomain.Default.TitleHeader,
                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                    Height = 25,
                    IsEnabled = true,
            };

            if (!(TitleH.Items.Count > 0))
            //TitleH.Role = MenuItemRole.TopLevelHeader; to get the triangle..
            {
                var listmen = List.Select(c => cMenuItem(c)).ToList();
                TitleH.ItemsSource = listmen;
            }

            contextM.Items.Add(TitleH);
            contextM.Items.Add(new Separator());
```

NB: no relevant XAML

Comment: What?? Why don't you use `ItemsSource` instead? You're trying to bend WPF to your will, which cannot be done. It's the other way around.

Comment: well i tried now your suggestion, and added the items to the list which i then gave to ItemsSource... works the same, no triangle appeared?

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: Hah solved :P

i had the context menu width set to aesthetical 160 pixel.

No go, you cannot make tidy and neat menus if you want to show triangles for submenus.

Setting the width to undeterminate large, now there are the triangles too!!

thx for attention..

Answer (score 0):

Solution: do not set the width of menu to some neat width, it will cut off the right hand side of the menu TOGETHER WITH the submenu marks (triangles) that will simply disappear.